# Passing the selected value of the radiobutton to action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I am very new to MVC, I have to display the value coming from the database in a table format and show the radio buttons in front of each display so that user can select whatever option they want to choose, I need to post that option to the controller. Below is what I am doing.

```
 @model IList<CertificateModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RefreshCertificates";
}
<h2>
    RefreshCertificates</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center; border: 5 px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Issuer
            </td>
        </tr>


        @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count - 1; i++) {
              @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x[i].Subject)
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].Subject, true, new { @name = "optionsRadios", @id = "rbtrue" })

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Subject)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Issuer)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.ActionLink("STANDARD", "SelectCertOk", "LogIn", new { Type = "STANDARD",  }, new { @class = "button" })
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is my model

```
public class CertificateModel
    {
        public string Subject
        {
            get { return cert.Subject; }
        }

        public string Issuer
        {
            get { return cert.Issuer; }
        }
   public bool validCert  { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller that is putting the data on the screen code is below:

```
public ActionResult RefreshCertificates()
    {
       certificates = new List<CertificateModel>();
       // some code here to fill up the list
      return View(certificates );
     }
```

The output that is displayed on the page is like this(RB is a radio button)

```
      Subject       Issuer
  RB     Coffee        Test1
  RB     Tea              Test2
```

From the current database only two are output on the screen. the user is only supposed to select only one of the radio button and then hit the actionLink button. 
My problem is that right now both the buttons are selected, i want only one of the radio button to be selected and also, I also want the value of that radio button to be posted to the controller.
so for e.g if the user selects Coffee and Test1 radio button then I want to pass

```
@Html.ActionLink("STANDARD", "SelectCertOk", "LogIn", new { Type = "STANDARD",  }, new { @class = "button" })
```

Type=STANDARD and SubjectIssue Coffee,Test1  to the controller. My controller signature is like this

```
 public void SelectCertOk(string Type, string SubjectIssue)
        {

    }
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the right thing, but unfortunately we can't override the name attribute like the id.
Update your view to include multiple radiobuttons with same 'name'.

```
@Html.RadioButton('Subject', x[i].Subject)

<a href="javascript:SelectCertOk();">STANDARD</a>
<script>
  function SelectCertOk(){
     var subject = $("input:radio[name=Subject]")
     $.post("@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/SelectCertOk")", { SubjectIssue : subject}, function (data) {}
     }); 
  }
</script>
```

But it won't solve your purpose.

So i would prefer to use javascript to check/uncheck radiobuttons.